# How to assign a model to a resource?

Tags: php, routes, model-binding, laravel-5.1

Consider this `routes.php` file:

```
Router::model('bar', 'App\Bar');
Route::resource('foo', 'AnyController')
```

Which will generate the following routes:

```
GET foo
GET foo/create
POST    foo
GET foo/{foo}
GET foo/{foo}/edit
PUT foo/{foo}
PATCH   foo/{foo}
DELETE  foo/{foo}
```

I need to bind a different model in routes. How to get it to produce the following urls instead?

```
GET foo
GET foo/create
POST    foo
GET foo/{bar}
GET foo/{bar}/edit
PUT foo/{bar}
PATCH   foo/{bar}
DELETE  foo/{bar}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the generated routes when using resource, since the idea is to save the work of defining them manually, however if you want you can define them by declaring the custom routes you want **before** your call to Route::resource; otherwise, the routes defined by the resource method may unintentionally take precedence over your supplemental routes